# JAXB fails to generate Java classes for XBRL

Tags: jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, xbrl, jaxb2-maven-plugin, cxf-xjc-plugin

I'm trying to generate Java classes for types defined in XBRL.

My build process is based on Maven 2, and here are my trials. I only paste the `build` section, which relies on some properties:

`package` is the name of my target package

`catalog` is the path and file name of the catalog. because I have no internet connection, I have amny entries, but I think those are always necessary

```
-- TR9401 for XBRL resources --
SYSTEM http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink http/www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd
SYSTEM http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink http/www.xbrl.org/2003/xlink-2003-12-31.xsd
```

`xsd.path` is the directory where the XSD resides

`xsd.file` is the file name of the following minimalist XSD

```
     <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xs:import namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
        schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd"/>
     </xs:schema>
```

All plugins I have tried fail to import `xl:nonEmptyURI`.

But `xl` is mapped to `http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink` (which is in my catalog) which imports  `<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="xlink-2003-12-31.xsd"/>` which defines  `nonEmptyURI`

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

## Apache CXF

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <catalog>${catalog}</catalog>
                                <xsd>${xsd.path}/${xsd.file}</xsd>
                                <packagename>${package}</packagename>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Fails with

```
parsing a schema...

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xl:nonEmptyURI' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 389 of cache/http/www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd
```

## jvnet maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- http://jaxb.java.net/ -->
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <catalog>${catalog}</catalog>
                <schemaDirectory>${xsd.path}</schemaDirectory>
                <generatePackage>${package}</generatePackage>
                <strict>false</strict>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.4</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.4</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The error is the same, a little more verbose

```
[INFO] Parsing input schema(s)...
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ cache/http/www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd{389,74}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: undefined simple type 'xl:nonEmptyURI'
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError(ParserContext.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.resolve(DelayedRef.java:110)
[...]
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ cache/http/www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd{412,77}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: undefined simple type 'xl:nonEmptyURI'
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError(ParserContext.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.resolve(DelayedRef.java:110)
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.2:generate (generate) on project solvency2: Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.2:generate (generate) on project solvency2: Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided.
```

## Mojo jaxb2-maven-plugin

```
         <plugin>
            <!--http://mojo.codehaus.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${xsd.path}</schemaDirectory>
                <packageName>${package}</packageName>
                <catalog>${catalog}</catalog>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Same error, said differently by Xerces

```
[ERROR] file:[...]cache/http/www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd[472,74]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xl:nonEmptyURI' to a(n) 'simpleType definition' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need all schemas to be downloaded and added to catalog in your case. I had a similar problem with generating Java classes, but I didn't use any catalogs at all just put all the schemas the XBRL uses into the same folder. The same way they're organized on XBRL site:

```
src\main\resources\xbrl\
                       xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd
                       xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd
                       xl-2003-12-31.xsd
                       xlink-2003-12-31.xsd
                       xbrl_bindings.xjb
```

Also I added a JAXB binding as you can see to resolve a conflict that raises during the source generation and put into the same folder.

xbrl_bindings.xjb:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          version="2.1">
         <bindings schemaLocation="xl-2003-12-31.xsd" version="1.0">
           <bindings node="//xs:schema//xs:element[@name='title']">
             <property name="xlTitle"/>
         </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Maven plugin configuration:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <bindingFile>${path.to.xsd}/xbrl_bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                                <xsd>${path.to.xsd}/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd</xsd>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Enjoy XBRL :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vladimir. I've put up a Github repository with a sample project at https://github.com/finlingua/xbrl-sec-example

Comment: How can i execute this file could you give me sample input data.it is asking input file as argument

Comment: Sarath, what kind of example do you want? These XSDs are available to public but if you need some more specific examples let me know. I'll get some for you.

Comment: usefull for me Upvode for that

Answer (score 0):

In your catalog, you probably need to change SYSTEM with PUBLIC.

See also: [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and)

According to this article, PUBLIC is used for matching a namespace URI:

```
-- Match address.xsd by URL --
SYSTEM "http://www.example.com/address/address.xsd" "imports/address.xsd"

-- Match phone-number.xsd by namespace URI --
PUBLIC "http://www.example.com/phone-number" "imports/phone-number.xsd"
```

Did you download the XSD and put it in an imports folder?

Comment: It's worse. Now I have *Failed to read schema document `http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd`*

Comment: And because, I want to use the catalog as a cache, I think I should use SYSTEM indeed; What makes you think PUBLIC should be used?